# How to write under or over "arrows"?

Tags: arrows, tikz-arrows

I made this files how to write under and over the "arrows" please

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\linespread{1.5} 
\textwidth=16truecm \textheight=23truecm  \voffset=-1truecm
\hoffset=-1 truecm \thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]  

\node (A) at (0,4) {$1$};
\node (B) at (   4,2) {$2$};
\node (C) at (  4,-1) {$3$};
\node (D) at (-4,-1) {$4$};
\node (E) at (-4,2) {$5$};


  \draw[
        decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.625 with {\arrow{>}}},
        postaction={decorate}
        ]
        (0,4) circle (0.4);
    \draw[ 
        decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.125 with {\arrow{>}}},
        postaction={decorate}
        ]
        (4,2) circle (0.4);

  \draw[ 
        decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.125 with {\arrow{>}}},
        postaction={decorate}
        ]
        (4,-1) circle (0.4);
        \draw[ 
        decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.125 with {\arrow{>}}},
        postaction={decorate}
        ]
        (-4,-1) circle (0.4);
        \draw[ 
        decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.125 with {\arrow{>}}},
        postaction={decorate}
        ]
        (-4,2) circle (0.4);
    % draw the connecting line
    \draw[ 
        decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}},
        postaction={decorate}
        ]
          (0,3.6)--(3.6,1.9) ;
          \draw[ 
        decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}},
        postaction={decorate}
        ]
          (3.6,1.9)--(3.6,-1);
          \draw[ 
        decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}},
        postaction={decorate}
        ]
          (3.6,-1)--(-3.6,-1);
           \draw[ 
        decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}},
        postaction={decorate}
        ]
          (-3.6,-1)--(-3.6,2);
          \draw[ 
        decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}},
        postaction={decorate}
        ]
       (0,3.6) -- (-3.6,2);
           \draw[ 
        decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}},
        postaction={decorate}
        ]
          (0,3.6)--(-3.6,-1);
           \draw[ 
        decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}},
        postaction={decorate}
        ]
          (0,3.6)--(3.6,-1);
            \draw[ 
        decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}},
        postaction={decorate}
        ]
          (3.6,-1)--(-3.6,2);
           \draw[ 
        decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}},
        postaction={decorate}
        ]
          (3.6,1.9)--(-3.6,-1);

    % draw the two black dots
    \fill (0,3.6) circle (0.1); 
    \fill (3.6,1.9) circle (0.1); 
    \fill (3.6,-1) circle (0.1); 
    \fill (-3.6,-1) circle (0.1); 
     \fill (-3.6,2) circle (0.1); 
    \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: you want to write some text label underneath each arrow?

Comment: @MichaelPalmer from 1-2 2-3, 3-4, 4-5, 5-1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Tikz, how to make the text on an edge have the same direction as the edge's?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67552/in-tikz-how-to-make-the-text-on-an-edge-have-the-same-direction-as-the-edges)

Answer (score 7):

for starting point:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc, decorations.markings, positioning, quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 20mm and 30mm,
     C/.style = {circle, draw=red, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, minimum size=8mm,
                 },
   dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2mm,
                 node contents={}},
     L/.style = {decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.4 with {\arrow{>}}},
                 postaction={decorate}},
every edge quotes/.append style = {anchor=north, sloped, font=\footnotesize},
every edge/.append style = {L}
                 ]
% main nodes
\node (A) [dot];
\node (B) [dot,below right=of A];%  {2};
\node (C) [dot,below=of B];%        {3};
\node (E) [dot,below  left=of A];%  {5};
\node (D) [dot,below=of E];%        {4};
% dots
\draw[L]    ($(A)+(0, 5mm)$) circle (5mm) node {1};
\draw[L]    ($(B)+( 5mm,0)$) circle (5mm) node {2};
\draw[L]    ($(C)+( 5mm,0)$) circle (5mm) node {3};
\draw[L]    ($(D)+(-5mm,0)$) circle (5mm) node {4};
\draw[L]    ($(E)+(-5mm,0)$) circle (5mm) node {5};
% draw the connecting line
\path   (A) edge ["some text"]    (B)
        (B) edge ["some text"]    (C)
        (C) edge ["some text"]    (D)
        (D) edge ["some text"]    (E)
        (E) edge ["some text"]    (A)
%
        (E) edge [pos=0.3, "some text"] (C)
        (D) edge [pos=0.3, "{$H(\{1\},\{2\})=\frac{1}{5}$}"] (B)
        ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

image is not completed, even for correct arrows orientation i'm not sure. this is simple to finish and with interchanges of coordinates easy to accomplish.

for text on paths i use `quotes` library. its syntax is simple:

```
 \draw (<coordinate 1>) edge ["text"] (coordinate 2);
```

to appear on desired side of arrows, to have desired font size, etc, i add to options to edge style:

```
every edge quotes/.append style = {anchor=north, sloped, font=\footnotesize}
```

also you can see, that i use relative positioning defined by library `positioning` od for driwing of edges names of nodes `dot`.  all this,. together to common style for decorations of paths, i define style `L`.

Comment: Please can i use \documentclass[12pt]{report}?

Comment: i have an error at the line 29

Comment: are you here? please answer me

Comment: ups, in copying code one comma was lost: correct is `every edge quotes/.append style = {anchor=north, sloped, font=\footnotesize},` . now corrected and tested again. it works as advertised :-).

Comment: it works but tht image is small why ? what about the document class

Comment: you can change document class to yours (`report` if i remember correctly), this will not change anything. only you need to add package `tikz` separately. used `standalone` is very handy to draw and test just one image. image is approximately the same size as with your code.  if you like to make bigger, you can scale it or better increase determined node distances.

Comment: please i can't write mathematics in "some text" $H(\{1\},\{2\})=\frac{1}{5}$ how to do ? i added \usepackage{amsmath}

Comment: i have a problem with the comma

Comment: problem is comma in your math expression. comma in any options delimit options. if it is in another function, as in your case, you need enclosed your expression in curly braces. see edited answer.

Comment: you have plenty new follow-up questions. pleas ask them as new question, which will be visible to wider audience.  temporary i cant offer you personal assistance. i'm convinced, that my answer solve your primary problem. for new problems, please again, ask new question(s).

Comment: i suggest you to ask new question, not edit this one. this become "newer end -story", so will suggest to close it as "not clear what you asking for"

Answer (score 0):

edge labels, written with quotes, is not trivial positioning above  and below, when they are sloped with edge, hence new answer. as (rude) solution is use of nodes as follows:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc, decorations.markings, positioning, quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 20mm and 30mm,
     C/.style = {circle, draw=red, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, minimum size=8mm,
                 },
   dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2mm,
                 node contents={}},
     L/.style = {decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.4 with {\arrow{>}}},
                 postaction={decorate}},
    EN/.style = {sloped, font=\footnotesize},
every edge/.append style = {L}
                 ]
% main nodes
\node (A) [dot];
\node (B) [dot,below right=of A];%  {2};
\node (C) [dot,below=of B];%        {3};
% dots
\draw[L]    ($(A)+(0, 5mm)$) circle (5mm) node {1};
\draw[L]    ($(B)+( 5mm,0)$) circle (5mm) node {2};
\draw[L]    ($(C)+( 5mm,0)$) circle (5mm) node {3};
% draw the connecting line
\draw   (A) edge node[EN,above] {some text above}
                 node[EN,below] {some text below} (B)
        (B) edge node[EN,below] {text}      (C)
        ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]