# Tikz arrow's label automatically following arrow's angle

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

Is there a way in Tikz to have the label angle computed automatically when adding a label on top of an arrow ? Here is what I am looking for :

```
\draw[->] (start) -- node[MAGIC HERE, above]{my label} (end);
```

Comment: Replace `MAGIC HERE` with `sloped`.

Comment: A couple of potential duplicates: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67552/ https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76172/

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant by "*label angle computed automatically when adding a label on top of an arrow*"?

Comment: @AndréC Sorry for the unclear question. I was looking exactly fro `sloped` but was not able to find it from a search engine. probably because of my English.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Can you convert your comment into a response?

Comment: Manuel, I closed the question as a duplicate. If you disagree just let me know.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. No problem for me and thank you for the answer and the stackoverflow job. Should I delete the question ?

Comment: No need to delete, it makes for another search target, if anyone else wonders about the same thing.